# Does the chunin exam ends with only one winner?

Tags: naruto

In the anime, they had a sheet where the participants' names were written for the finals of the chunin exam.

[image]

If Orochimaru along with the sand and Sound ninjas, had not attacked Konoha during the chunin finals, would the exam finish with one winner by having 2 semi finals and a final after the Gaara vs Sasuke match?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is explained by *Sandaime Hokage* that, though there is one winner of the tournament, it doesn't guarantee that he will become a *chunin*.

He also explained that there can be more than one *chunin* from an exam and there can be none too.

If there was only one *chunin* per exam, it would have been impossible for all  of Naruto's friends to become *chunin* after his 3 years of training with *Jiraiya*.

Comment: Additionally, I am pretty sure you can become a Chuunin if the higher ups accept it (hokage + village elder). You can definitely become Jounin if your teacher suggests and the Hokage allows it (ie Minato).